# How to get wasm-ld to honor wasm-import-module attribute

Tags: llvm, webassembly, wasi

Fixed: I set the DLL storage class of the function I was importing to `dllimport`, and that allowed wasm-ld to emit the correct import namespace.

I am building a compiler with the LLVMSharp* library, and it emits LLVM .bc module files targeted to `wasm32-unknown-unknown`. I am trying to import functions into it from the WASI interface by tagging those function values with the `{ "wasm-import-module"="wasi_unstable" }` attribute. (This should be equivalent to what clang does with `__attribute__((import_module(<module_name>)))`; see [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#import-module)). However, when I pass the resulting .bc files to wasm-ld (the Windows 64-bit 9.0.0 installed version), the resulting .wasm module still imports those functions from `"env"`, which doesn't work.

Is there some option to pass to wasm-ld to get it to handle `wasm-import-module` correctly, or do I need to go another route?

*Specifically, I'm using LLVMSharp 5.0.0, which is the latest stable version. It's possible that LLVMSharp 8.0.0 may support building .wasm modules, but there isn't a release NuGet for it, and the beta NuGet has some problems that prevent me from upgrading. That's why I'm going the wasm-ld route.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please consider adding some of your code so we can help you debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wasm-ld should support this attribute.  The first thing to check is your object file.

You can use `llvm-readobj --syms` to dump the symbols in your object file.   You should see `ImportModule: foo` on your symbol where `foo` is the module name you specified in your attribute.

I looks like the support for this landed in wasm-ld in: https://reviews.llvm.org/D45796

I believe this change landed just before llvm 8.0, so you will llvm 8.0 or above.

Comment: You were right; the object file was wrong. I needed to set the DLL storage class of my imported function to `dllimport`.

For those using Windows as I was, the `llvm-nm` tool is what allowed me to view the symbols in my .bc file--the `llvm-readobj` tool does not seem to exist or to get installed for Windows.

Comment: @BenLeedom Can you share what your LLVM looked like to make this work?